# Retaining primary symbology in gdb file in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, file-geodatabase

After importing my feature class into a gdb file for sharing, its primary symbology was changed back to default (i.e single symbol).

Is there a way to retain the intended primary symbology (i.e unique values) after it is being imported to a gdb?

Rather than having a separate layer package for this, I would like it to be saved together with other features in the gdb.

Comment: Symbology can be saved out as a layer file, so prepare your layer as you want it to look then right click on it in the contents pane then sharing>save as layer file. Then you load only that file into other projects.

Comment: Regarding, "I would like it to be saved together with other features in the gdb," the answer is you can't store layers in a geodatabase.  That is partially why Esri created the layer package, so the layer and data could be bundled together for sharing.